# Can 'viability' refer to the difficulty of implementing a method?

Tags: word-choice, terminology

I am writing a paper where I need to provide comparisons about different methods/instrumentations designed for a same task. One of the characteristics I would like to show is the amount of efforts one should cost to get that method implemented (in terms of the price, complexity of the system, and so on).

So can I use 'viability' to indicate this property?

Thanks!

Comment: Consider tying your shoes, or sending a rocket to the moon. Both are viable, but one is much more difficult than the other.

Comment: It's generally not as gradable as *difficulty*. It's more of *either it is or it isn't*.

Comment: The most relevant definition of *viable* is "capable of working, functioning, or developing adequately". This is subtly different from the difficulty of getting it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the word options provided by @ Jack are good words for your purpose.

In the question, it is basically a question of showing benefit against cost. These following words may be a better fit to this situation.

[Doability](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/doability) (Wiktionary) Feasibility; practicability.

[Achievability](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/achievability) (Wiktionary) The state or condition of being achievable.

[Effectiveness](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/effectiveness) (Wiktionary) The property of being effective, of achieving results.

```
The effectiveness of the drug was well established.
```

The capacity or potential for achieving results.
The degree to which something achieves results.

```
He questioned the effectiveness of the treatment.
```

The word "**economy**([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/economy))" means effective management of a community or system, or especially its resources. This is what the question is asking for in the word. Some economy derived words are

[Economicalness](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/economicalness) (Wiktionary) The quality of being economical.

[Cost-effectiveness](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cost-effectiveness) (Wiktionary) Returning a benefit that justifies the initial investment; economical.

Sadly "[economicality](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=economicality%2Ccost-effectiveness%2Ceconomicalness&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ceconomicality%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ccost%20-%20effectiveness%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcost%20-%20effectiveness%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCost%20-%20effectiveness%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCost%20-%20Effectiveness%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCOST%20-%20EFFECTIVENESS%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceconomicalness%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ceconomicality%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ccost%20-%20effectiveness%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcost%20-%20effectiveness%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCost%20-%20effectiveness%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCost%20-%20Effectiveness%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCOST%20-%20EFFECTIVENESS%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceconomicalness%3B%2Cc0)" is not a proper commonly used English word.

As mentioned in the question "viability" can be used. Viability([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/viability)) is derived from "viable([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/viable))" which is derived from Latin *vītābilis (“capable of life”).

Answer (score 1):

"Practicality" or "practicability" or "feasibility* might fit.

[M-W *practicality*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/practicality)
3: capable of being put to use or account

[M-W *practicability*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/practicability)
1: capable of being put into practice or of being done or accomplished : feasible

[M-W *feasibility*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/feasibility)
1 : capable of being done or carried out

*Viability* is also possible, but it could have a wider meaning.

I suggest the word *expend* in place of the word *cost* in your question.
*Cost* is the effect of an expense on someone who is spending.
*Expend* is the action of one who is spending.

Answer (score 0):

since the word "viability" means "the capability of success of sth", i think it can be used.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).